# ansible loop in playbook

Tags: python, loops, ansible, cisco

I am playing with `nxos` module to configure Cisco switch using ansible and had one question related loop handling.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_network_modules.html#nxos

I have this task where i need to configure channel-group on all interface but adding `1` in interface number so if interface is `E1/12` channel-group will be `112`

```
interface Ethernet1/11
  channel-group 111 mode active
interface Ethernet1/12
  channel-group 112 mode active
interface Ethernet1/13
  channel-group 113 mode active
interface Ethernet1/14
  channel-group 114 mode active
interface Ethernet1/15
  channel-group 115 mode active
```

I have currently this snippet in ansible to doing all interface related task

```
- name: default interfaces
      nxos_interface: interface={{ item }} description='Configured by Ansible' mode=layer2
      with_items:
        - Ethernet1/11
        - Ethernet1/12
```

is there anyway i can some kind of loop in above code to iterate in variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like below:

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name:  default interfaces
      debug:
        msg: "1{{ item.split('/')[1] }}"
      with_items:
        - Ethernet1/11
        - Ethernet1/12
```

Output

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=Ethernet1/11) => {
    "msg": "111"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Ethernet1/12) => {
    "msg": "112"
}
```

The "1" is fixed here